# Три условия в Excel

Tags: excel

Есть три условия, но почему-то последнее условие **ЕСЛИ(C4>=8001)** показывает неверный результат.
В чем ошибка?

=ЕСЛИ(C4>=2501;C4-((C4*2%)+((C4*3%)+(C4*0,5%)+((C4-2500)*25%)+(2500*14%)));ЕСЛИ(C4<=2501;C4-((C4*2%)+(((C4-200)*14%)+(C4*3%)+(C4*0,5%)));ЕСЛИ(C4>=8001;C4-(2500*14%+(C4-2500)*25%)-(C4*3,5%)-(160+(C4-8000)*0,5%))))

Comment: Только последнее неправильно? Странно... В формуле ошибки.. `(C4-2500)25%` - Что такие записи означают? Надо множить на 25%? Куча-куча лишних скобок... Зачем так - *250014%*, если мжно записать просто - *2500,14*? Как будто специально писали формулу так, чтобы в ней было сложнее разбираться

Answer (score 0):

может вместо C40,5% надо C4*0,5% и так далее... у меня все посчитало без ошибок